# Find set of non-overlapping rectangles in a 2D grid

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, np-hard

I have a $n \times m$ rectangular grid of cells, and a set $R$ of rectangles within this grid.  Each rectangle is a subset of the cells.  (Alternatively, you can think of them as axis-aligned rectangles where each of the four corners has integer coordinates.)

I want to find a subset $S$ of rectangles, so that $S \subseteq R$, so that no two rectangles in $S$ overlap, and so that $S$ is as large as possible.  (Alternatively, you can think of this as finding a maximum independent set in a graph where we have one vertex per rectangle, and an edge between two rectangles if they overlap.)

Can this problem be solved in polynomial time?  Is it NP-hard?

I can see how to solve the one-dimensional analog (maximum set of non-overlapping intervals) in polynomial time using dynamic programming, but that algorithm doesn't seem to extend to this case.  Wikipedia calls this the [maximum disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set) problem and says that when the set of shapes is arbitrary, the problem is NP-hard, but it doesn't discuss the specific case of axis-aligned rectangles with integer coordinates.  That makes me suspect this problem might be NP-hard, but I haven't found a reference or proof of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you state is shown to be NP-Hard [1, 2]. However, there is an $O(\log \log n)$ approximation algorithm for the problem [3].

[1] H. Imai, T. Asano. Finding the Connected Components and a Maximum Clique of an Intersection Graph of Rectangles in the Plane. Journal of Algorithms 4(4): 310-323, 1983.

[2] R.J. Fowler, M.S. Paterson and S.L. Tanimoto, Optimal packing and covering in the plane are NPcomplete. Information Processing Letter. 12 3 (1981), pp. 133137.

[3] Parinya Chalermsook, Julia Chuzhoy: Maximum independent set of rectangles. SODA 2009: 892-901